Set XML parameters dynamically in transform message
I have a flow that makes a request to soap service, and before the request I need to transform input JSON to XML:

I tried setting Qualified Name as dynamic property:
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns ns0 http://tempuri.org/
---
 {
 
 ("ns0#" ++ (vars.operation)): {
        ns0#intA: payload.val1,
        ns0#intB: payload.val2
    } 
}

but when I make a Postman request, I get:

Error consuming the operation [Divide], the request body is not a valid XML

I made it dynamic using if and else:
{
    (
        if (payload.operation == "Add") {
            ns0#Add: {
                ns0#intA: payload.val1,
                ns0#intB: payload.val2
            }
        } else if (payload.operation == "Multiply") {
            ns0#Multiply: {
                ns0#intA: payload.val1,
                ns0#intB: payload.val2
            }

But I was hoping for a more dynamic solution

The question is not fully clear. Does the second script work? Are there any error in the the logs for either script? What are the inputs and outputs of each script? What exact version of Mule are you using?

To add to what aled asked, what is the output that you are expecting?
